# Not finding eth0 while using VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

I am trying to setup an SSH connection to my virtual Ubuntu machine so that I can connect to it from my laptop on external networks. When using `ifconfig` eth0 does not show up, nor does any other valid IP address. I am running Ubuntu 16.10 in Oracle's VirtualBox.

The two things that show up are `enp0s3` and `lo`

I also ran `sudo lshw -C network` to make sure that my VM was picking up the ethernet connection and it appears to be.

I can take screenshots and post them if it would help diagnose my issue.

Also I am newish to the LinuxOS, so if anyone could link me to beginner guides for Ubuntu, that would be great!

Comment: `enp0s3` is normal due to the change to [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: After a little more digging I think I have found what the issue was and how to solve it. The issue was that the IP address was showing up as 127.0.0.1/8 but now that I have changed what the VM's network adapter to 'bridged' it works fine